# What is a float, have I got the right idea?

Tags: python, floating-point

I was programming a calculator and I came across float. I was told to use floats then my calculator would be able to calculate calculations including numbers like `16.4` and `4.5` and not just whole numbers.

Now, I sort of got thinking and wondered if someone could just verify I'm on the right tracks.

I understand an int is a solid number, a double is basically 2 numbers with a dot in the middle, a decimal? And now comes the tricky one, the float data type.

I just need somebody to verify I'm on the right track. I think a float is a data type that can either be a whole number (this is what I'm not sure about) and a double/decimal.

I feel like float is the safe data type kinda thing, where you're not sure and want to accept whole and decimal numbers, am I right? Is it for accepting both whole and decimals?

For anyone that struggles to understand, heres the code to my calculator, it might help.

```
while True:
    calculation = input("Calculation: ")

    if (calculation.__contains__("+")):
        print(float(calculation[0] ) + float(calculation[2]))

    elif (calculation.__contains__("-")):
        print(float(calculation[0] ) - float(calculation[2]))

    elif (calculation.__contains__("*")):
        print(float(calculation[0] ) * float(calculation[2]))

    elif (calculation.__contains__("/")):
        print(float(calculation[0] ) / float(calculation[2]))
```

Comment: Sure thing, I just assumed it would be applicable to all languages.

Comment: The tag was removed, but in C `float` is like `double` but with less range and precision.

Comment: Why not read [IEEE Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic (IEEE 754)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)?

Comment: You probably should just read what [IEEE754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) is. Floats and doubles are essentially the same thing, one is 32 bit, the other one is 64 bit. (Correction: this doesn't seem to hold in Python; the question was originally also tagged with a whole bunch of other languages)

Comment: I just wanted to ensure I was using it for the right reason, to accept whole and decimal numbers. I feel like you guys have answered that. @sascha I will definitely do that.

Comment: And of course: [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://www.itu.dk/~sestoft/bachelor/IEEE754_article.pdf)

Comment: You definitely do not want to think of floating-point objects as holding integer and decimal parts. Floating-point formats are most commonly binary based, not decimal based. (Even if you are using a decimal-based format, thinking of it as an integer part and a decimal part has some problems.) You should understand from the beginning that floating-point arithmetic **approximates** real arithmetic (not decimal arithmetic). It is not preferentially decimal, and trying to match it to decimal operations will encounter problems. Either learn the format well or expect approximation errors, or both.

Answer (score 2):

A float is a floating-point number (more or less your "basically 2 numbers with a dot in the middle").

The term double is short for "double precision floating-point number": a similar kind of number but typically using more bits to store it, allowing for more precision.

In Python, the type `float` is used to refer to all floating-point numbers, regardless of precision.

Comment: Python's `float` has only one amount of precision, the same as 64-bit IEEE.  It does not auto-size like Python's `int` does.  If you need more precision, you can use something like `numpy.float128` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You mention Python's `float` and also `double`.  These are exactly the same thing, because what Python calls `float` (pedantically, in most implementations of Python) is what everyone else calls `double`.  And what C and C++ call `float` does not exist in Python.